# Building a jar with sources included with Gradle using the Kotlin DSL?

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle

I've got a small Kotlin library that I'm building with the Gradle Kotlin DSL, so my `build.gradle.kts` looks something like this:

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.5.31"

    `java-library`
}

group = "foo.bar.api"
version = "1.0"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom"))
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")

    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test")

    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit")
}
```

I'd like to be able to build a jar that includes both the compiled code and the sources. I know that I can get a separate sources JAR via:

```
java {
    withSourcesJar()
}
```

But I haven't been able to figure out the right incantation to build a JAR that includes both the sources and the compiled code in a single artifact.

Comment: That's a very strange demand from your side. Maven and Kotlin know how to deal with sources (and Javadocs) in external JARs, that's how the whole system works now. What is the profit of combining them to a single Jar?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm aware it's not the usual or recommended way of doing things, but it works for my use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably tweak the `jar` task, not the Java Plugin extension (the top-level `java` clause). Try this:

```kotlin
tasks {
    withType<Jar> {
        from(sourceSets["main"].allSource)
        duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    }
}
```

I tested it quickly in my project and it seems to work, but due to some quirks I need that `duplicatesStrategy`. It should probably work without that for you.